# Prevent the distortion of HTML elements when increasing zoom percentage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on the UI for a website and it looks perfect when the zoom is set to 75%. But if I zoom in any more than that, shapes get wonky and elongated, and distorted. For example, a `<div>` that **should** be a square will become a rectangle.

What I want: To completely prevent this from happening, I want the shapes to remain in their original state and for the page to not change in appearance upon zooming in/out. The only thing I want zooming to do is to zoom in on something, not enlarge it or distort it.

Here are some pictures of what I mean:

1. How it should look - `<div>`s are square-shaped here:

[image: Square-shaped at 75%]

2. How I don't want it to look after zooming in:

[image: Distorted after zooming in]

Tried: setting a specific height and width for all divs in the CSS.

For example,

```
height: 200px;
width: 250px;
```

Did not work!

Any help is greatly appreciated! I do not want anything to change size or shape at all! By the way, I am using Bootstrap on my page.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-3">
                
                  <div class="wrapper-vids">
                      <div class="stranger-peer-vid">
                        <video class="video-s" id="videoS" autoplay></video>
                      </div>
                      <div class="local-peer-vid">
                        <video class="video-l" id="videoL" autoplay></video>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                
              </div>
```

Here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.wrapper-vids {
    margin:11px;
    contain: content;
}

video {
    transform: scaleX(-1);         /* mirror effect*/
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* mirror effect*/
}
.stranger-peer-vid {
    height: 350px;
    width:480px;
    background: black;
}
.local-peer-vid {
    height: 350px;
    width:480px; 
    background: black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    
}
.video-l {
    height: 350px;
    width:480px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.video-s {
    height: 350px;
    width:480px;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelM. Okay I added some arrows ... the first photo where the divs look more square, is ideal - how I want it to look no matter what zoom is set to.

Comment: You need to build your layout based on the general allocation of the entire page. For example, if your side panel should take 30% of the page and you specify it in `%` instead of `px`, it will scale naturally. However, the more common practice is to use different CSS styles for different screen resolutions/scale. Try to zoom in on this StackOverflow site, and you will notice that at some point, the central part will take more space, and the right column will hide. This is because CSS switches styles depending on available space.

Comment: Search for `responsive web design` to see examples and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks @RAllen - I am using BootStrap so it is a fractional system, meaning one panel takes up 1/3 of the page or whatever.. I think I can tweak that based on resolution. BootStrap should allow me to do that.. I am just looking for some easy trick

Comment: please, provide a working example of your code

Comment: Done.. added some code.